# How to combine objects and write out separately in if statement

Tags: r, datatable, tidyverse

In R ,there data object/tibble names are 'data1,data2,data3,data4.....data100'(they are have same structure)

1. how to combine all of them
2. how to out put to csv files separately

Below code failed, anyone can help?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
file <- ls(pattern = 'data') 
# rbind to a big dataframe
total_file <- rbindlist(file)

# write object to csv separately
for (i in c(1:100)){
  write.csv(paste0("data",i),paste0("data",i,".csv"))
}
```

Comment: See the linked posts, one is for importing the other one is for exporting. You are doing both wrong.

Comment: in the linkage , the data ready to write out are in a list , in my question the object are stored separately in RAM , please help  Thanks!

Comment: Then there is no need for *rbindlist*, try: `for(i in (ls(pattern = "data")){ write.csv( get(i), paste0(i, ".csv")) }`. I added more relevant 3rd link.

Comment: Thanks , the  get() function can solver my question.